# even after specifying that users id not equal to 15 still it being shown in mysql results

Tags: mysql

I am making a query in which i require to specify not to show that result if the user id is 15 . but still it shows the results with the user id 15 . my query is

```
SELECT u.uid, u.religion FROM users_profile u LEFT JOIN partner_prefrences p ON u.uid=p.uid and CONCAT(',',p.religion,',') LIKE CONCAT('%,',u.religion,',%') and u.uid!=15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT u.uid, u.religion 
  FROM users_profile u LEFT JOIN partner_prefrences p 
    ON u.uid=p.uid and CONCAT(',',p.religion,',') LIKE CONCAT('%,',u.religion,',%') 
 WHERE u.uid != 15
```